# Pure virtual default destructor

Tags: c++11

One of the things I find myself doing everytime I write a base interface is to declare and define a pure virtual destructor. Why C++11 does not allow a default definition of a pure virtual destructor?

```
struct Ibase
{
    virtual Ibase* basefun1() = 0;
    virtual ~Ibase() = 0 = default;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of the base class is *always* called explicitly when an object of a derived class is destroyed.

So if it isn't defined, there will be a link error.